# SQL CE give back summed values of timeranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, timestamp, modulo

Given a table with following entries (simplified to get the idea)

```
timestamp | value 1 | value 2
60          12        0
120         13        0
180         10        12
240         8         0 
....
3600        11        0
3660        41        12
3720        14        8
....
```

- *Table has each minute logged for one whole year (525600 entries)*
- *timestamp is primary key*
- *using SQL Server Compact aka SQL CE in V4*

Task is  to get the summed values of each value-col of each hour, so not just row #3600 (= 1hour) value #1 : 11 (which could be done via modulo), but all previous values of this hour summed (12 + 13 + 10 + 8 + ... + 11).

Is there a SQL Query to achieve this?

Comment: If you are using SQLServer WHY did you tag `MYSQL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I have misinterpreted, you should just be able to do this with a GROUP BY, assuming that timestamp is an integer

```
SELECT [timestamp]/3600 AS HourNumber, 
    SUM(value1) AS Total1, 
    SUM(value2) AS Total2 
FROM #data 
GROUP BY [timestamp]/3600
```

I've not used SQL CE, but I can't imagine it would work any differently on something so fundamental as integer arithmetic and basic grouping

Comment: oh , so simple and beautiful. thank you very much!

Comment: By the way for those who may have the same problem - I was hoping to get a faster result from this approach in terms of filtering, but to get the whole dataset in C# and filter it inside (while reader.read) is 2x faster.

Comment: Interesting. I'd say in my experience, it is better to just use the database to store data, and not try to do any manipulation in SQL. As an SQL dev who enjoys writing complex queries, it makes things more boring, but I think its often the right approach to keep things as simple as possible when accessing the db. In practice though, SQL is often the easiest part of a system to change, so things often get done there out of expediency

Comment: Finally I implemented another approach, that is - creating two dbs in parallel, one with hourly and one with minute values. It is ugly, but IMHO the fastest way. Goes in line with what you're saying.